bash sourced command silently fails under WSL2 vs direct execution from shell?
I have a Bash script which evaluates JSON file to set environment variables and creates a function
The script works fine under native Ubuntu (22.04LTS), but when you run the same script under WSL2 (Windows 11), it fails to create environment variables and make the function -- silently -- there is no error message.
HOWEVER, if you copy paste the relevant lines to your WSL2 bash prompt, it processes them OK.
The script is called via ". funcs.sh" and it looks like this:
#!/bin/bash
. mode.sh
# load config JSON as env vars (export)
eval $(cat config.json | jq -r ".${MODE}"' | to_entries | .[] | "export " + .key + "=\"" + .value + "\""')
# DELIM is set here because it is static in daily_import_header.sql:
export "DELIM"=";"
# logging to graylog server
log() {
        APPNAME="SPAR"
        # assumes LOG_SERVER to be set by eval
#       if [ "${LOG_SERVER}" eq "" ]; then
#               LOG_SERVER="redacted"
#       fi
        if [ $# -eq 2 ]; then
                PRI=$1
                MSG=$2
        elif [ $# -eq 1 ]; then
                MSG=$1
                PRI=INFO
        else
                echo "Usage: $0 [priority] <message>"
                return 1
        fi
        logger -p ${PRI} -t ${APPNAME} -n $LOG_SERVER ${MSG}
}

mode.sh in this case contains only string:
export MODE=PROD

. funcs.sh silently doesn't create variables/function
. mode.sh works (variable MODE=PROD is created)
pasting
eval $(cat config.json | jq -r ".${MODE}"' | to_entries | .[] | "export " + .key + "=\"" + .value + "\""')

to the same bash prompt works, after ". mode.sh" was run (variables are created).
Any suggestions appreciated.

So the question is really like about ("nested") source, instead of eval, right?

@TomYan Hmm, I guess you are right, I should probably change the title. Essentially the same command when run directly from shell works, but when sourced -- doesn't .
